# Could a binary star system support life?

Tags: science-based, earth-like, survival

If we take an earth-sized planet with similar atmosphere, and put it into a P-type binary orbit, could it sustain human life? For sake of clarity, assume both stars are G-type stars and the planet is orbiting at 1-2 AUs from the stars.

Comment: _P-type_ means _planetary-type_ (circumbinary) as opposed to S-type (satellite-type) [by the way](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/38745/what-do-the-words-p-type-and-s-type-mean).  Lots of this is discussed in [this XKCD what-if](https://what-if.xkcd.com/150/).  If you are far enough from the binary to have a stable orbit (about 6x the distance between the stars) then they will never be more than about 20° apart in the sky, so, provided the orbit is stable, it will be surprisingly similar to orbiting a single star.

Answer (score 18):

It’s plausible.

[Research indicates that low mass binary stars may be especially suited to supporting life.](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/extraterrestrial-life-may/) Granted, this article discusses stars of a lower mass than G-type stars, and planets orbiting at greater AU, but this is a promising sign.[Real research in astrophysics is being done to determine the habitability zones of binary star systems](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fspas.2021.640830/full) Given that this is an ongoing topic of research, and one that is fairly young, it is reasonable to have a binary star system posses the right features for supporting life.

Answer (score 10):

As told [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitability_of_binary_star_systems) it is possible for S-Type and P-Type planets to be in habitable zone..

Studies of Alpha Centauri show that Centauri A and B have an 11 au distance at closest approach (23 au mean), and both have stable habitable zones for non-circumbinary (S-Type) planets.

Kepler-47c is a gas giant in the circumbinary (P-Type) habitable zone of the Kepler-47 system.

If Earth-like planets form in or migrate into the circumbinary (P-Type) habitable zone, they would be capable of sustaining liquid water on their surface in spite of the dynamical and radiative interaction with the binary stars.

For more details, read [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5384241/) and [here](https://www.davincisciencecenter.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Madison-Salter.pdf).